# HTML form input readonly

Tags: html

i'm currently using readonly for html inputs,.. but in some of html version (I think so) it can be editable,.. is there any other option instead of readonly to make it noneditable?

my input tag is

```
<input type = "text" id = "plan_amount" readonly>
```

`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the content inside a div and make it look like one of your form element using CSS.

Comment: You can use Span/Div tags for showing those in text format instead of using Input tag.

Comment: thax, but i need to post those value.. now i'm using disabled  with two input tag.. thanx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use disabled attribute: `<input disabled>`.

And you can add an `<input type="hidden">` if you want to POST the value.

Comment: Be aware that disabled inputs are not POSTed.

Comment: thanx... But i need post those value.. how can i?

Comment: One input `<input disabled>` to display value to user and one input `<input type="hidden">` with value is POSTed.

Comment: Have you try this solution ?

Comment: sry for the delay,. I tried,.. can show the disable attribute, but It can be editable in the hidden field.